# I cant use R selenium at all in a specific page

Tags: r, authentication, rvest, rselenium, bigdata

It get stuck when Rselenium meets this URL, it will be all right if I change to some other webpage.as you can see the below code "getCurrentUrl"& "getPageSource" are the most basical operation.

```
url = "https://sycm.taobao.com/custom/login.htm?_target=http://sycm.taobao.com/"


# Build up the environment -----------------------------------------------------
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
pDrv <- phantomjs(port = 4567L)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "firefox", port = 4567L)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)


#show the page -----------------------------------------------------------------

remDr$maxWindowSize()
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

# basic operation by seleniumR
remDr$getCurrentUrl()
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Works with google chrome:

```
appUrl <- "https://sycm.taobao.com/custom/login.htm?_target=http://sycm.taobao.com/"


# Build up the environment -----------------------------------------------------
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate(appUrl)


#show the page -----------------------------------------------------------------

remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

# basic operation by seleniumR
remDr$getCurrentUrl()
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

rm(rD)
gc()
```

And for Firefox:

```
appUrl <- "https://sycm.taobao.com/custom/login.htm?_target=http://sycm.taobao.com/"
# Build up the environment -----------------------------------------------------
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox")
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate(appUrl)

#show the page -----------------------------------------------------------------

remDr$maxWindowSize()
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)

# basic operation by seleniumR
remDr$getCurrentUrl()
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
rm(rD)
gc()
```

Comment: If I use your way , this error shows again as below , I tried many times to solve it but failed then I choose another way to use Rselenium which I also found here . Please help if you are quite experienced about this . 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rD <- rsDriver()
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : Couldn't connect to server

Comment: Hey . It still gets stuck when you come to 
remDr$getCurrentUrl()
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] .  you just changed a browser .

Comment: Seems to be an problem with phantomjs. Raise an issue on the project page https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues

Comment: is it for the defense from the webpage , as the page is from Alibaba , they did something to detect thoes actions from machine .  but its really  a simple operation, I just want get the current URL(solving this I could do more). if I change the url I want to scrape, then it shows well .